# vbscript execute command to file

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, wmic

I am trying to execute a batch command from within vbscript.

I want the output to be written to a file.

When I run it, I get no output to the console or to the file.

I'm trying:

```
Dim objShell, command
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.shell")
command = "wmic product get Name > textfile.txt"
objShell.Run command, 0, True 
Set objShell = Nothing
```

What am I doing wrong?

When I run the `wmic` command in a command prompt it works well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to add cmd in front of the command such as:

```
command = "cmd wmic product get Name > textfile.txt"
```

in addition to using the cmd keyword there are also several switches you can use depending on your needs.  You can see  them by typing cmd /? in a command prompt window.

Here are a couple:

```
/C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates
/K      Carries out the command specified by string but remains
/S      Modifies the treatment of string after /C or /K (see below)
/Q      Turns echo off
/D      Disable execution of AutoRun commands from registry (see below)
/A      Causes the output of internal commands to a pipe or file to be ANSI
/U      Causes the output of internal commands to a pipe or file to be Unicode
```

Comment: You should use `cmd /c ...` not just `cmd ...`.

Comment: I do use /c in my actual script but that doesn't make it right in all instances.  I wanted to keep the answer general.

Answer (score -2):

```
command = "cmd wmic product get Name > textfile.txt"
```

Modify for this

```
command = "cmd wmic product get Name >> textfile.txt"
```